# Branch cut choice for $(z+\frac{1}{z})^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z)=(z+\frac{1}{z})^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

It has branch points at $z=0$ , $z=+i$ , $z=-i$. I am trying to select a branch cut in such a way that $g(z)$ is analytic in the annulus $|z|>2$. I have tried for hours with no avail. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Hm.... Finding branch like that means finding a branch $\log_\tau$ of $\log$ such that for any $|z|>2$ one has arg$(z+1/z)\neq\tau$. I don't think that's possible.